# How to make and update ranking in database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ranking

I have this query:

```
Select [col], DENSE_RANK() Over(ORDER BY col DESC)as rank From Table
```

I have 2 column, x and y.
But i want to update data in column x with result of DENSE_RANK(). Honeslty, i don't know how can that's query work, but when i try, that's work.

But when i tried that's query in query builder, will appear a warning "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported." . So i need to make ranking of data in column x, then save the result of ranking into column y.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below. Here `b` and `a` are table alias. You need to join with the same table -> get the ranking data -> and then update the desired column

```
UPDATE a 
SET y = b.rank
FROM Table a
JOIN (
Select x, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x DESC)as rank From Table ) b
ON a.x = b.x;
```

Comment: Then, how can i getting ranking of my data in column x then save the result of ranking into column y?

Comment: My bad ... removed my previous answer. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, column x and y is in 1 table. b is a table too right?

Comment: No, `b` here is a table alias. You need to join with the same table -> get the ranking data -> and then update the desired column.

Comment: @StevanSetiawanWijaya no, `a` is a alias for `Table`, see `FROM Table a`. `b` is a subquery that is also operating on `Table`, that subquery is named `b`.

Comment: So if my table name is score, the query is: FROM SCORE a. Right?

Comment: @StevanSetiawanWijaya, Yes, BTW that table alias `a` could be any name you want. Consider reading about SQL to gain more knowledge.

Comment: @StevanSetiawanWijaya, also consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button under voting button.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, i'm so helpful. But when i create that query in dataset, still appear SQL Syntax Errors Encountered with message "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.". That is because i'm using SQL Server 2005.